# How can i show wordpress page with next.js according to url

Tags: node.js, reactjs, wordpress, next.js

Actually, I want to show the WordPress page with the next according to URL

Example

mydomain.com -> need to show next.js page
mydomain.com/otherpages-link -> need to show next.js page

mydomain.com/blogs -> need to show WordPress page.

I cannot use WordPress as a headless cms with next.js due to some specific reason.

Comment: In these circumstances it would be a better decision to use a subdomain like  `blog.mydomain.com`  and point it to wordpress site. Otherwise, you need to mess around with nextjs router settings which is not a good idea.

Comment: then seo will rank my blogs.mydomain.com instead of the original domain